# SQL Query is not reformatting date on PHP file using DATE_FORMAT method?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date-formatting

By default, PHPMyAdmin has the datetime column formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, but I'm trying to reformat it into MM-DD-YYYY using an SQL statement on my PHP file. This is the code I used, but it's not working:

```
<?php
$usertext = $_POST['textinput'];
$insertsql = "INSERT INTO testtext (usertext) VALUES ('$usertext')";

if (isset($_POST['textinput'])) {
    require '../db.php';
    mysqli_query($db, $insertsql);
}

$selectdate = "SELECT textdate, DATE_FORMAT(textdate,'%m/%d/%Y') AS newdate FROM testtext";
$dateresult = mysqli_query($db, $selectdate);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dateresult)) {
    echo "{$row['textdate']}<br>";
}
?>
```

This code is able to display rows from the 'textdate' column onto my test site just fine, but the DATE_FORMAT code was unable to reformat the date. Can you please help me fix this code? Thanks so much.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample  ..

Comment: What does `$row['newdate']` look like?

Comment: @rickdenhaan $row['newdate'] doesn't show the date, just an empty string. $row['textdate'] does show the date though, but not in desired format.

Comment: @John Conde Thanks for the info and letting me know. I was just testing this script first since it's easier. I was going to work on security after.

Comment: What is the data type of your `textdate` column? Is it one of the `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` types, or is it a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` type?

Comment: @rickdenhaan the datatype is DATETIME and the default is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your formatted date `newdate` but are referring to `textdate` in your code. You need to refer to that alias you assigned the results of `DATE_FORMAT()` to and not the original column identifier.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dateresult)) {
    echo "{$row['newdate']}<br>";
}
```

Comment: But when I change it to {$row['newdate']}, the date doesn't show up. I think it's because the table in my database is called 'textdate' and 'newdate' doesn't exist there.

Comment: Do `var_dump($row);` and see if the value exists in the results

Comment: @codo7081 nope, you are wrong. Newdate is a field alias. If nothing shows up there, then either the conversion went wrong annd it returned null, or some other error occured.

Comment: @John Conde hey it works now! It seems I was supposed to echo out newdate instead. Thanks so much for your help!!